# process with an id is not running visual studio 2010

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, process, operating-system

I created simple **asp.net** web application .When I tried to run the application ,it's giving me error pop up saying "**process with an id xxxx is not running visual studio 2010**".Need your help.I tried following thing, but they did not help.

```
project--> properties-->web-->servers  : selected "Auto -Assign Port"(Not working)

project--> properties-->web-->servers  : selected "specific port (not working)"
```

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/t/1946251.aspx?VS+2010+2012+2013+Ultimate+IIS+Express+Process+with+Id+of+xxxx+is+not+running+
Try this

Comment: I'm not using IISExpress. Please help